# Need to get the count different from content and library table using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have folder,content,library table. Each folder has lot contents in both content and library tables.
content and library tables are depended with content_id. If we add content, it should saved both content and library table.
Sudendly there must happened the deletion in library table. some of the content are deleted in library table but not in content table.

I want retrieved the particular folder id,count of the content in that folder, count of library in that folder.

I try some options i can able to retrieve the folder id (content presented in content table not in library table). use single query to retrieve the folder_id count(content_id content table),count(content_id library table)

```
select distinct a.folder_id from (
select c.folder_id,c.content_id, l.content_id as lid from content c left join library l
on c.content_id = l.content_id
where l.content_id is null) a
```

result:

```
folder_id  ccount lcount countdiff
123         33      30      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select
  a.*,
  ccount-lcount as diff
from
    (
    select
      folder_id,
      (select count(*) from content c where c.folder_id=f.folder_id) ccount,
      (select count(*) from library l where l.folder_id=f.folder_id) lcount
    from
      folders
    ) a
```

Comment: Result Query:select
  a.*,
  ccount-lcount as diff
from
    (
    select
      folder_id,FolderPath,
      (select count(*) from content c where c.folder_id=f.folder_id) ccount,
      (select count(*) from library l where l.parent_id=f.folder_id) lcount
    from
      content_folder_tbl f where folder_id in (select distinct al.folder_id from (
select ct.folder_id,ct.content_id, li.content_id as lid from content ct left join library li
on ct.content_id = li.content_id
where li.content_id is null) al)
    ) a